# Display a full width div below a smaller image in a mosaic

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have an HTML structure with a mosaic of image : 4 images per row.

When I click on an image, I would like to make a full-width div appears below the row where the image is.

And I need to have that element (`.div-full-with`) to remain in flow.

Here is a schema :

[image]

I’ve tried absolute positioning but the element is not in flow of course.

```
.div-full-with {
        background-color: #333;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        height: 100px;
        top: 30px;
      }
```

I’ve tried some other technics (calculate, etc) but I can’t achieve this.

If the structure was static, it would be very easy. But I'm in a loop and I have to make it in a template like this where there is only only one element :

```
<div class="col-md-3">

    <img src="..."/>

    <div class="hidden-div">some content in full width</div>

</div>
```

Comment: You'll need to set some breakpoints in JavaScript to determine the amount of columns in a row at certain widths. It helps if you make these breakpoints overlap with breakpoints in CSS. Then when clicking an element, determine where a *full-width element* should be appended that spans all columns in a row based on the current breakpoint.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier ok,I had hoped to find a simple solution with basic html/css but it seems it is not possible. When I saw this web mockup, I didn't realize it would be hard to code.

Comment: Yeah, it will need some JavaScript. But it does not mean that it has to be difficult. Think about like this. At width X you got 3 columns. So if you click on an image, after every multiplication of 3 you should temporarily add your full-width element. So after column 3, 6, 9, etc.

Comment: But wait, I've read over the part where you said that you **always** have four items in a row. That way you don't have to do any calculations, but only have your full-width element with a height of `0` at default and animate it to a certain height when an element in that row is clicked. Still needs JS, but it's much easier.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Thank you. Your comment helps me and I see what I could do. I was too focused on html/css.